# soming about the adt, virtual devices

Tags: android, eclipse-adt

I'm first time to use the adt

when i unfold the target option, there is no android 2.3 or below version

therefore I would like to know how and where should I add these version in the Target

thanks a lot!

http://s24.postimg.org/adavkl49f/123.png

Comment: Upload image again. Current link is dead.

Comment: Eclipse ADT is no longer supported by Google. switch to More POWERFUL Android Studio now.

Answer (score 1):

Open Android SDK Manager (from the toolbar in Eclipse) to install more targets. Eclipse just helps you by installing the most recent target.